# Sum * Columns Where Date Between

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to LINQ and have a simple statement that selects all the columns between two dates.

I would like to sum each column. I am having some trouble with getting my sql statement as follows.

```
   var PumaGoodProduct = (
            from item in db.tbl_dppITHr
            where item.ProductionHour >= StartShift && item.ProductionHour <= EndDate
            orderby item.ID descending
            select item).Sum();
```

with the following i get a error saying that .ProductionHour does not contain a defination for sum.

I have also tried this

```
        var PumaGoodProduct = (
            from item in db.tbl_dppITHr
            where item.ProductionHour >= StartShift && item.ProductionHour <= EndDate
            orderby item.ID descending
            select item).Take(1);
```

Any ideas on this would be great thanks.

I would like to select item.MachineTotal and item.MachineClocks both are ints

Comment: what's the type of ProductionHour?

Comment: DateTime i dont need to sum the this feild.

Comment: Then what do you need to sum? can you add some sort of description of item, and exacly what property do you want to be summed?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to order if you're just doing a sum.  Also, you'll need to select which property you're summing on.

```
var PumaGoodProduct = (
    from item in db.tbl_dppITHr
    where item.ProductionHour >= StartShift && item.ProductionHour <= EndDate
    select item).Sum(x => x.MySumProperty);
```

Replace `MySumProperty` with whatever property you're looking to sum.

Comment: How do sum more than one column?

Comment: If you're looking for on value, you can do `.Sum(x => x.MySumProperty1 + x.MySumProperty2);`  If you're looking to have two running totals, you're going to need to look into `group by`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're computing two sums, one way to combine them in a single return type would be:

```
var PumaGoodProduct =
    new
        {
            MachineTotalSum =
                (from item in db.tbl_dppITHr
                    where item.ProductionHour >= StartShift && item.ProductionHour <= EndDate
                    select item).Sum(x => x.MachineTotal),

            MachineClocksSum =
                (from item in db.tbl_dppITHr
                    where item.ProductionHour >= StartShift && item.ProductionHour <= EndDate
                    select item).Sum(x => x.MachineClocks),
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to return multiple sums from your query against column `item.MachineTotal` and `item.MachineClock`, you can try the following.

```
var result =  (from item in db.tbl_dppITHr
              where item.ProductionHour >= StartShift 
                    && item.ProductionHour <= EndDate
              select new 
                   {
                     SumMachineTotal = item.MachineTotal, 
                     SumMachineClock = item.MachineClock
                   }).FirstOrDefault();

if(result != null)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Machine Total Sum: {0}" , result.SumMachineTotal);
   Console.WriteLine("Machine Clock Sum: {0}" , result.SumMachineClock);
}
```

You don't need `orderby`, since `Sum` would calculate the sum irrespective of the `orderby` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to venture a guess here. You want to obtain the sum of both the `MachineTotal` and of the `MachineClocks` fields of the items in `db.tbl_dppITHr` in the given `StartShift` and `EndDate` period.

You could do that like this:

```
var PumaGoodProduct = db.tbl_dppITHr
        .Where(item => item.ProductionHour >= StartShift && item.ProductionHour <= EndDate)
        .Aggregate(new { MachineTotalSum = 0, MachineClocksSum = 0 },
        (sums, item) => new
        {
            MachineTotalSum  = sums.MachineTotalSum  + item.MachineTotal,
            MachineClocksSum = sums.MachineClocksSum + item.MachineClocks
        });

Console.WriteLine("MachineTotalSum  : {0}", PumaGoodProduct.MachineTotalSum);
Console.WriteLine("MachineClocksSum : {0}", PumaGoodProduct.MachineClocksSum);
```